# Trouble understanding the definition of adjoint functors

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

Let $\mathcal{C,D}$ be two categories and $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$, $G:\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{C}$ be two functors. We say that $(F,G)$ is a pair of adjoint functors when $$\text{Hom}_\mathcal{D}(F-,-)\simeq\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(-,G-), $$
that is, these functors are naturally isomorphic.
Ι have some trouble understanding this and I cannot find a precise meaning to it.

Does that mean that whenever we fix an object $X\in\text{Ob}\mathcal{C}$ the functors $\text{Hom}_\mathcal{D}(FX,-)$ and $\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(X, G-)$ are naturally isomorphic and whenever we fix an object $Y\in\text{Ob}\mathcal{D}$ the functors $\text{Hom}_\mathcal{D}(F-,Y)$ and $\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(-,GY) $ are naturally isomorphic?

Comment: They're naturally isomorphic as functors on $\mathcal{C}^{op}\times\mathcal{D}$, is the simplest way to look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct way to understand this isomorphism is by viewing these functors as having domain $\mathcal{C}^{op}\times\mathcal{D}$. In particular, the left side is the composite $$\mathrm{Hom}_\mathcal{D}\circ F^{op}\times id_\mathcal{D}:\mathcal{C}^{op}\times\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{D}^{op}\times\mathcal{D}\to\mathbf{Set}$$
and the right is
$$\mathrm{Hom}_\mathcal{C}\circ id_{\mathcal{C}^{op}}\times G:\mathcal{C}^{op}\times\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{C}^{op}\times\mathcal{C}\to\mathbf{Set}$$

This turns out, in this particular case, to be equivalent to what you've guessed above with respect to fixing one of the arguments. The benefit of the above presentation is you can describe it as a single ordinary natural isomorphism instead of a family of natural isomorphisms between families of functors.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think something is missing: I can prove that given your definition the functors that have one argument fixed are isomorphic (quite simply) but I cannot prove the converse: doesn't there have to be an extra condition? I mean something like a compatibility between the isomorphisms of the one-arg-fixed natural isomorphisms?

Comment: You're right that it's not obvious. However, $\mathrm{Hom}_\mathcal{D}(F-,Y)\simeq\mathrm{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(-,GY)$ for all $Y$ is enough by itself to derive the bifunctor case, and the other single argument case, though it takes some work to show this. I suspect there's a more elementary route through Proposition 2 of II.3 in Mac Lane, but on reflection I can't swear that my idea of how to use this works.